# I'm getting errors while running my flutter app

Tags: flutter

Hey there I'm building an audio app using audioplayers package in flutter and in my code I don't have any error but when I run my app using flutter run, I'm getting these errors attached in the image.
[image]

Comment: This [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558023/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-audioplayerscompiledebugkotlin) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following Commands

Step 1->

```
flutter clean
```

Step 2->

```
flutter pub get
```

Step 3->

```
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Commands

```
flutter clean
```

then run

```
flutter pub get
```

OR
Delete your flutter cache folder inside flutter/bin directory and then try to run